Firebase Analytics iOS SDK signature cannot be verified error
I'm using Azure Artifacts to download third party libraries. I have uploaded firebase analytics  SDK v10.22.0 and it is working fine. When trying to update SDK 10.24.0 getting an error in Xcode
same as Here
Note: When directly download .xcframworks and add framework into Xcode works fine. Issue happens only when trying to download from azure artifacts.
I use download artifacts.py referred Artifacts-Download
Reached out to Google but they said could be an issue in Azure artifacts. Appreciate the help
Tried the solution given here

Use copy -Crp option
Clear xCode cache , derived data etc.
but didn't help



How did you upload your package to Azure Artifact? 2. "Issue happens only when trying to download from azure artifacts." - How did you try to download from Azure Artifact? How did you configure your project with Azure Artifact? 3. To download Universal Packages via CLI, you need to connect to the feed firstly. Have you followed the steps in Publish and download Universal Packages in Azure Artifacts?


@ZiyangLiu-MSFT Yes I have followed the steps. As mentioned it was working fine when uploading and downloading firebase analytics sdk v10..22.0. Issue happens when trying to download uploaded (updated)version v10.24.0


If you can successfully download package v10.24.0 using Azure DevOps CLI? 2. "When directly download .xcframworks and add framework into Xcode works fine" - Would you please help clarify what "directly download" means? Where did you download it from?


If I download directly from [here] (https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk) and  add .xcframework into Xcode then it works fine.  If I upload the same .xcfrmawork iinto azure artifacts and then download to the source throws an error

The actual issue is when uploading .xcframworks into azure artifacts it doesn't preserve symbolic links


"The actual issue is when uploading .xcframworks into azure artifacts it doesn't preserve symbolic links" - If it is, firebase analytics SDK v10.22.0 should also had the same issue. But according to your reply, it works. 2. Have you tried Firebase Apple 10.28.0? Will you have the same error in Xcode?


No V10.22.0 doesn't have code signing and symlinks. Google added code signing in in V10.24.0

Yes Even if I update to v10.28.0 will have similar issue

Would you please add your .xcframworks in a .zip file and publish the .zip file to Azure Artifact? Then check if the symbolic links are preserved.

Sure @ZiyangLiu-MSFT. Thank you for the suggestion

Feel free to let me know if you have any update or question.

Hi @ZiyangLiu-MSFT, I have uploaded as .zip but not clear on how to unzip in my python script. Is there a way to check if the downloaded artifacts is .zip and then do unzip it ? Appreciate your help

Figured out extracting zip and adding to the target. Thanks again. @ZiyangLiu-MSFT

Hi @Sugans, thanks for your update. May I know whether the symbolic links are preserved in the .zip file? Did adding .xcframworks in a .zip file resolve your issue?

@ZiyangLiu-MSFT I'm adding as swift package as zip in artifacts and download. Because azure artifacts upload and downloads removes the symblinks so after adding as zip didn't help. Thanks again for the help
